# When i copy a file, LastModified value does not change on Mac?

Tags: java, macos

When i copy a file, the LastModified value remains the same. I want to detect which one of the file is the copied one - Im thinking i can get it by analyzing the LastModified value. The most recent one will be the copied one. But i cant do this on Mac because both files have the same value. Is there any other way.

Comment: *I want to detect which one of the file is the copied one...* They have different names. How could you mix them up?

Comment: How do you copy them? Please show the code.

Comment: Copying is done manually using UI by copy/paste. It could be copied to a different directory. @DiabolicWords

Comment: @shmosel This is a problem to solve. I didn't mix them up. What do u mean ?

Comment: Why do you need the modification date to know which one is the copied one? Who's doing the copying?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes and no.

Mac OS, other than of Windows, does not change the *created* and *modified* dates when you copy a file.

So **no**, there is **no other way** finding out which file is the copy as long as you try to solve it **only by comparing timestamps**.

But **yes**, you could achieve a comparison by changing the filename and **adding something recognizable** like '_copy' or the like **to the filename**.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the [stat](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) command.

```
$ stat -x your file
```

it should print something like:

```
  File: "foo"
  Size: 30           FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (  501/   user)  Gid: (    0/   wheel)
Device: 1,4   Inode: 3477348    Links: 1
Access: Fri Apr 13 13:36:11 2018
Modify: Fri Apr 13 13:35:57 2018
Change: Fri Apr 13 13:35:57 2018
```

Then copy the file and run again the command, you will notice that the `Access` field will change.